# "Unknown Entity namespace alias" in form type

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1

I am getting the error **Unknown Entity namespace alias 'DummyUserBundle'** when using a custom entity field in a Symfony2 form type. I really don't figure out what the reason is. The error only occurs if I am trying to customize the field.

This fails:

```
<?php
namespace Dummy\Bundle\TasksBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('assigned', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'DummyUserBundle:User',
            'label' => 'My own label',
            //custom query builder coming here once I get this working
        ));
    }
}
```

This however works:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('assigned');
}
```

In my config.yml I have `auto_mapping: true`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just use Dummy\UserBundle\Entity\User

Comment: Works, thanks! Is this the way it is designed? Do namespace aliases only work within they same bundle?

Comment: This fails since Symfony2.1, not sure why.